Cgo: call go function from c executable, who start go runtime?
Cgo.  When i call to go functions from c process . When and how the go runtime started.  What if i have 2 go project compiled into shared object and wrapped by cgo ,  is go runtime will run twice?
Why cgo must to have func main?
I created test that one c main call to 2 different go shared object
Each go shared object have wrapped by cgo
When i run the cgo SO were conflict and crash
Only when i dedicate c thread to each SO the conflict and crash stop
Alternatively i wrapped the 2 So with one common cgo
It it work good
I wonder ,when go runtime start in this flow?
Is it run twice on the main thread?
